# Organise Active Storage files for use in other systems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

Active Storage stores uploads in a file structure like so:

[image]

This is great if the rails app is the only software that needs to use these files.

But what if the app simply serves as a means to upload the images to S3 so that some other (completely separate) service can consume them?

The problem being, other developers wouldn't be able to make any sense of the directory and files, since they're labelled in a way rails can understand, but which a human cannot (e.g. what does folder named "O2" mean?).

Is there some way to ensure uploads are stored in a human-friendly way? e.g. each folder could be a user_id, with their assets inside? (or similar)

Comment: This is really beyond the scope of ActiveStorage. ActiveStorage is general purpose storage solution that works without any particular knowledge of your application and with various backends. Its not the right tool for those requirements.

Comment: @max since the rails app 'knows' how to map each file (blob) back to a meaningful filename and use, could that somehow be harnessed (say, as a once off, or batch, process) to map the arbitrarily named blobs to meaningful file names?

Comment: the specific use case is building an internal app where users will input product information, and that product info will get consumed by other applications. I guess the best solution is to simply build an api? Perhaps transferring the link to the file in s3, or even simply encoding it in base64 and sending it as a string?

Comment: Yeah but that would really mean that you would have to write an entire customized backend for ActiveStorage. But doing that kind of defeats the entire purpose of using ActiveStorage which is to provide a quick and easy fix and might prove to be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @max okay, I'll heed your advice and build something bespoke. Really appreciate the advice

Comment: Creating an API is definely an alternative. If you're operating at cloud scale the whole idea of human readible file names is kind of moot. Its not like you're gonna be going in and browsing it manually when there is a huge number of files.

Comment: @max okay, I'll give the API a shot before trying something bespoke. I think that will work given the other apps don't care *where* the files are stored (i.e. strange folder/file names), so long as they know what exactly is stored under which path, which I think is possible to provide (just need to tinker with Active Storage a little). Thanks for all the help

Comment: Yeah your API can just provide the products and links to the files. You generally want to avoid base64 encoding as it increases the response size by about 30% and requires that your application server serves the files instead of S3 or an edge cache.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you would have to implement an own service that somehow replace the `key` used to something else (e.g. [S3Service](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb)), or patch ActiveStorage to create the key itself in a different way. I am not sure that this would suffice though, as the key is most likely used for other critical functionality outside of the Service.

Alternatively you might poke in [ActiveStorage::Blob](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0475215d4fa1a6db2a92a0065081fe19c64cc124/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L154) to fiddle with the `key`. That said, ActiveStorage does not support what you'd like out of the box and you would have to take the risk of messing with its internals.

A solution to the problem (but not answer to you question) might be implementing an API as outlined in the comments to your question.